# ASP.Net Core IHosted background service внезапно выключается

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, iis

Ищу помощи, уже всю голову сломал. В общем есть приложение ASP.NET Core Razor Pages (.Net 5), хостится на IIS. У приложения есть фоновый сервис, который по расписанию запускает несколько методов. При выполнении приложения происходит 2 проблемы:

1. Фоновый сервис прекращает работу через 20 минут (IIS настраивал на бесперебойную работу).
2. Фоновый сервис при выполнении определенных действий выключается.

При этом, если приложение запустить из командной строки, то все работает прекрасно и без сбоев. Пробовал, оборачивать все в try catch для обработки исключений, но их нет. При поиске проблем обнаружил, что если в методе CheckChanges в цикле foreach (var ca in result.УдостоверяющийЦентр.Where(x=>x.РеестровыйНомер != 0)) закоментить исполянемый код, то сервис не падает.
P.S. Проблема только в IIS.

В логах приложения:

```
info: CronJobUpdateCA[0]

08:50:00 CronJob is working.

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

Application is shutting down...
```

Вот код сервиса:

**BackgroundService.cs**

```
public abstract class BackgroundService : IHostedService
{

private Task _executingTask;

private readonly CancellationTokenSource _stoppingCts =
                                               new CancellationTokenSource();

public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

    if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        return _executingTask;
    }

    // Otherwise it's running
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Stop called without start
    if (_executingTask == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        _stoppingCts.Cancel();
    }
    
    finally
    {
        await Task.WhenAny(_executingTask, Task.Delay(5000,
                                                  cancellationToken));
    }
}

protected virtual async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    do
    {
        await Process();

        await Task.Delay(30000, stoppingToken); //5 seconds delay
    }
    
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
    
}

protected abstract Task Process();
```

}

**ScopedProcessor.cs**

```
public abstract class ScopedProcessor : BackgroundService
{
private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

public ScopedProcessor(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory) : base()
{
    _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
}

protected override async Task Process()
{
    using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        await ProcessInScope(scope.ServiceProvider);
    }
}

public abstract Task ProcessInScope(IServiceProvider serviceProvider);
```

}

**SchedulerProcessor.cs**

```
public abstract class ScheduledProcessor : ScopedProcessor
```

{
private CrontabSchedule _schedule;
private DateTime _nextRun;

```
protected abstract string Schedule { get; }
public ScheduledProcessor(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory) : base(serviceScopeFactory)
{
    
    _schedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse(Schedule);
    _nextRun = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    do
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        if (now > _nextRun)
        {
            await Process();
            _nextRun = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
        }
        await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken); //5 seconds delay
    }
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
}
```

}

**SchedulerTask.cs**

```
public class ScheduleTask : ScheduledProcessor
```

{

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public ScheduleTask(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, IConfiguration configuration) : base(serviceScopeFactory)
{
   
    _configuration = configuration;
}

protected override string Schedule => "*/2 * * * *";

public override Task ProcessInScope(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    

    var updater = new CAUpdater(_configuration);
  
        updater.Test();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

**метод Test**

```
public void Test()
    {
        
        ReadFile(); //Десериализация xml файла.
        CheckChanges();
    }
```

**метод CheckChanges()**

```
private void CheckChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            var context = new ApplicationContext();
            Update upd = new Update();
            upd.Date = result?.Дата ?? DateTime.Now;
            upd.Version = result?.Версия ?? 0;
            upd.FileName = fileName;
            upd.Error = _errorBody.ToString();
            update = context.Updates.Add(upd).Entity;
            
            if (result == null)
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
                return;
            }
            
            foreach (var ca in context.CA.Where(x => !x.Deleted).ToList())
            {
                if (result.УдостоверяющийЦентр.All(x => x.РеестровыйНомер != 0 ? x.РеестровыйНомер != ca.Id : x.КраткоеНазвание != ca.Name))
                {
                    ca.Deleted = true;
                    context.CA.Update(ca);
                    
                    context.СaChanges.Add(new СaChange()
                    {
                        Update = update,
                        CA = ca,
                        Action = "Delete",
                    });

                }
            }
            
            foreach (var ca in result.УдостоверяющийЦентр.Where(x=>x.РеестровыйНомер != 0))
            {   
                var item =
                    ca.РеестровыйНомер != 0
                        ? context.CA.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == ca.РеестровыйНомер)
                        : context.CA.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == ca.КраткоеНазвание);
                // дальше идет код......
            }
                }
```

Comment: Почему вы выполняете синхронную работу в асинхронном методе? Я нахожу это странным. Если это CPU-Bound операция, то есть смысл вынести `CheckChanges` в отдельный поток, но у вас здесь работа с базой. Эта работа может выполняться асинхронно, верно?

Comment: IIS отрубает пул, если количество необработанных исключений (в том числе из неуправляемого кода) превысит какое-то значение (у меня в русской винде этот параметр называется "Максимум сбоев")

Comment: @АлексейОбухов Да, параметр этот я нашел. Попробовал вообще защиту от сбоев отключить, и о чудо, код стал выполняться корректно. И теперь пул постоянно перезапускается. В логах: Application was recycle after detecting app_offline.htm. Из-за чего вообще такое может происходить?

Comment: `СaChanges` - первая буква русская. остальные английские - жестоко...

Comment: [app_offline.htm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/app-offline?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - описание этого файла. Вырубается из-за его появления. Осталось разобраться, откуда он берётся. | Вот [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21528) разработчики долго выпытывают детали у автора такой же проблемы, но безуспешно.

Comment: В документации по [hosted service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) примеры кода содержат логирование. Вот с этого и следует начать. Добавьте в свой код вывод логов и по ним, вероятно, можно будет разобраться.

Comment: согласен, вставьте через каждую строчку кода логирование (ну или хотя бы в catch). не просто так же приложение падает. может привилегий каких не хватает (iis запускает приложения не из под текущего пользователя, как в случае консольного приложения).

Comment: @АлексейОбухов Большое гранд мерси. В итоге все заработало. После того как я отключил настройки сбоев в IIS я нашел причину. У меня в одном из методов создавался файл, но пул продолжал держать его по какой-то причине видимо и из-за этого перезапускался. Try catch не давал ошибок. В итоге я сделал, чтобы файл создавался каждый раз новый, и после этого перезапуск пула пропал. Сервис работает корректно.